# Check autofilled value with Playwright

Tags: typescript, playwright, autofill

I am testing with Playwright and faced one problem.

On web I've a form with 4 fields. When 2 of them are filled, in third one appears calculated value. Expect.soft returns on this new appeared value received string: ""

As example I've this part of code:

```
await page.getByLabel('Buy up price').fill(buyUp); // fill Buy up price
await page.getByLabel('Percent of sale price').fill(percent); // fill Percent of sale price
if (percent != '') {
    let salePrice = ((+buyUp) * (+percent)/100 + (+buyUp)).toFixed(8);
    const predictPrice = page.locator('//*[@id="fvf_salePrice"]');
    await expect.soft(predictPrice).toHaveText(salePrice, {timeout: 5000});
} else {
    await page.getByLabel('Sale price', { exact: true }).fill(salePrice); // fill Sale price
}
```

In debug mode I see value on selector //*[@id="fvf_salePrice"] exists, but expect.soft part allways fails, it returns:
expected string: salePrice
received string: "".
I see that playwright catch placeholder, where value displyed, but can't get right value. Actually I've used all types of selectors (Xpath, CSS, etc.), used while loop to wait until data renew, but nothing helped. Testing is performed on chromium

Is it because of dinamically changing data, or something wrong in code?

Comment: Try clicking the input first await page.locator(inputSelector).click()
Then page.locator(inputSelector).fill('value')

Comment: Or you could try page.locator(selector).focus() then page.keyboard.type(value)

Comment: Could you share the site or a represtative mockup of it so it's possible to write a verified, reproducible answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all, I've found a solution.
As it was an input field, toHaveText() must be replaced with toHaveValue().
So await expect.soft(predictPrice).toHaveText(salePrice, {timeout: 5000}); must be replaced with expect.soft(predictPrice).toHaveValue(salePrice, {timeout: 5000});

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).